# MKDirectionsRequest returns a wrong path

Tags: ios, mapkit

My iOS app uses `MKDirectionsRequest` to find a path between a source location and a destination location. The destination location is 'fixed'. It is Leiden Centraal Raylway Station in the Netherlands.

There are two scenarios:

1) I launch `MKLocalSearchRequest` for "Leiden Centraal" query and obtain `MKMapItem`. Then I use this `MKMapItem` as a destination in `MKDirectionsRequest`. The path returned is good:

[image]

2) I create the destination `MKMapItem` manually using

```
MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:coord addressDictionary:dict];
mapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placemark];
```

The `coord` is exactly the same `MKLocalSearchRequest` returned to me in scenario 1.
The dictionary `dict` has keys `@"CNPostalAddressStreetKey"`, etc.

The path returned also leads to the Leiden station. But it's wrong, because it goes through a street which seems to only be used for deliveries. And it it doesn't even exist as a street on Google Maps:

[image]

So what am I doing wrong? How can I create a destination `MKMapItem` so that the path returned would be correct? Or maybe it would be possible to serialize the "correct" `MKMapItem` returned by `MKLocalSearchRequest` to use it in future?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try by passing nil instead of address dictionary ?

```
MKPlacemark *placemark = [[MKPlacemark alloc] initWithCoordinate:coord addressDictionary:nil];
mapItem = [[MKMapItem alloc] initWithPlacemark:placemark];
```